# Add string in csv file via windows batchscript

Tags: csv, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a pipe delimited csv file like below

```
METADATA|WorkTerms|PeriodOfServiceId
MERGER|WorkTerms|WT10127
METADATA|Assignment|WorkTermsAssignmentId|PeriodOfServiceId
MERGER|Assignment|WT10127|WR10127
```

I want a output like below

```
METADATA|WorkTerms|PeriodOfServiceId(SourceSystemId)
MERGER|WorkTerms|WT10127
METADATA|Assignment|WorkTermsAssignmentId(SourceSystemId)|PeriodOfServiceId(SourceSystemId)
MERGER|Assignment|WT10127|WR10127
```

I want to add (SourceSystemId) at specific places, can this be done via windows Batch script ?

Any leads, links suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks,

Shivam

Comment: You cannot edit a file inline using batch without re-writing it to a temp file, then deleting and renaming it. I would suggest you would rather use powershell.

Comment: Can it be done if we can edit the file and rename it and place it at some other folder ? I don't have any issues unless I get a files with this data added be it by writing it to Temp file.. please share how to proceed on this ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how ?

Comment: Thanks, waiting for it !!

Comment: please let's clean up some comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, replace the name of **`myfile.csv`** in the 4th line only, with the name of **your** csv file and te path to the file in the 3rd line.. If the strings you want to replace are the only strings, do not touch anything else in the script. place the script in the same directory as your files:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "mypath=C:\PATH\TO\CSV"
set "mycsv=myfile.csv"
move "%mypath%\%mycsv%" "%mypath%\oldmyfile.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%mypath%\oldfile.txt"') do (
    set "str=%%i"
    set "edit=!str:PeriodOfServiceId=PeriodOfServiceId(SourceSystemId)!"
    set "edit=!edit:WorkTermsAssignmentId=WorkTermsAssignmentId(SourceSystemId)!"
    echo !edit! >> "%mypath%\%mycsv%"
)
del "%mypath%\oldfile.txt" /Q
```

Here is what the script does. Renames the original file to oldfile.txt, type each line and make it a variable, do a replacement of certain fields, but the fields that does not match the search string will remain in tact, then it will echo the lines to the original file name including the replacements.

Comment: Thanks man it worked perfectly, If I want to keep the batch file in some other directory how would it work ? I tried like  "%mycsv%" "C:\users\shivam\Desktop\Taleo Files Folder\oldmyfile.txt" but this didn't worked..

Comment: Yes, if you want to keep it in another directory it can be done. I will edit the example to cater for that.

Comment: Edited, please have a look at the 3rd and 4th line, only change path in the 3rd line and filename in the 4th.

Comment: If the path have spaces, will this still work ? mine gave error that could not find

Comment: the double quotes will handle that for you, make sure you copy the code exactly as it is now.

Comment: Thanks, you are so helpful :)